# Ajax .done() no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I am using the following jquery to make an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/projects/project/xGetProjectStatus",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"})
    .done( function(request){
            alert(request.responseText);
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            if(data.success){
                   //stuff here
            }
})
```

The alert pop up always says that responseText is undefined. The page I am "get"ting is well formatted JSON and if I run these commands in the console one at a time everything works fine. What is wrong?

Comment: What does `console.log(request)` say?

Comment: `request` doesn't have a `responseText` property unless you give it one on the server side.

Comment: @KevinB I know... :) I was asking OP to print it.... So will realize what he gets is what he expects as `responseText` but as parsed Object.

Comment: You are doing `dataType: "json"`.  That tells jQuery to call `JSON.parse` for you.  Your `request` parameter *is* your (*already parsed*) object.  `if(request.success){}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `responseText` in the response, it won't be there. You'll find it instead on the `jqXHR` object itself (which is the third parameter passed to your `done()` function, and also returned by your whole `$.ajax()` call).

And because you have `dataType: "json"` the response is already a JSON parsed object.

Change this:

```
.done( function(request){
     alert(request.responseText);
     var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
     if(data.success){
          //stuff here
     }
 })
```

To just this:

```
.done( function(data){
    if(data.success){
          //stuff here
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `dataType` in a `jQuery.ajax` call it will be returned as a parsed object. So your `request` object in `.done` is actually your parsed `json` string

If you don't want `jQuery` to automatically parse your JSON you can remove the datatype from the call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/projects/project/xGetProjectStatus",
    type: "GET"
}).done( function(request){
     alert(request.responseText);
     var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
     if(data.success){
         //stuff here
     }
})
```

Comment: Removing the `dataType` won't make the code work as you have shown.  First off, if you don't give a `dataType`, jQuery will try to guess based on the MIME type.  If the URL returns a `Content-type: application/json` header, then jQuery will parse it for you anyway.  Second, the `responseText` property is on the `jqXHR` object, which is *NOT* the 1st parameter.  It should be the 3rd parameter: `.done(function(data, status, jqXHR){})`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first parameter of the done function is not the XHR object but the contents of the responseText as an object already.  jQuery handles all that for you and so there's no need to do any manual conversion.

the done function is called whenever the ajax call is successful anyways so no need to re-check it and the fail function is called when a response other than 200 is returned.

Comment: He's not "re-checking" if it was successful.  He's checking the `success` property of the object he retrieved from the AJAX call.

Comment: Ahh ok, well personally, I'd prefer to use the status codes to dictate whether or not an operation was successfull instead of passing it as a bool in a json object.  Return 200 if the operation was a success, return some other 40x status code if there was a problem. Reduces the payload sizes by removing moving information like that to the header.